# ODI KM odiRef.getColList documentation incomplete : selector "RG"

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I'm trying to reverse some code a former employee wrote without documentation. My firm updated from ODI 12.1 to ODI 12.2 and I found the line responsible.

The code is inside a step of a KM.

This line doesn't work :

```
odiRef.getColList("", "[MANDATORY_CLAUSE]", "; ", "", "((INS and !RG) and REW)")
```

This line works

```
odiRef.getColList("", "[MANDATORY_CLAUSE]", "; ", "", "((INS and !TRG) and REW)")
```

As you can see, the "RG" Selector is responsible for the crash.

It is not a typo mistake as the "RG" Selector is working in ODI 12.1

My problem is that I don't know what this selector does as it is not present from the Oracle Documentation...

The last argument is a boolean to choose which colonne to pick. For exemple TRG means Target and will  choose only for mapping expressions executed on the target.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/integrate.1111/e12645/odiref_reference.htm#ODIKD1048

Does anyone know what the selector "RG" does ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is quite strange to me that RG works, because it has always been TRG ( Target ).

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like there is an issue with ODI 12.1 not erroring out on an unknown selector rather than "RG" being an undocumented selector. So my assumption is that "RG" does nothing at all.